# Show or hide a widget from pages

Tags: widgets

I want to add a check option to the wordpress admin sidebar when I am writing a post or a page to display a specific widget. I tried display-widgets plugin but I want to be able to show a widget directly while writing the post.

Or is there is another way to do this it will be OK.

Comment: Other than the checkbox on the post edit page, does the display-widgets plugin do what you want?

Comment: The plugin is ok, but I want another easy and speed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring the discovery of a plugin that does this already (I'm not aware of any that specifically do what you want) you'll need to create your own. [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and `add_filter('widget_display_callback', $instance, $widget, $args)` should be the bulk of what you need

Comment: This what I have done after a long time of search and it works fine. Thanks